# PHP page not recieving POSTed jquery ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have my first PHP page having search form:

```
<form action="#" class="form-inline" id="form_srch">
  <input type="text" id="toSearch" name="toSearch" placeholder="Enter Application Number" class="form-control" style="width:250px" required >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="search()">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
  <i><b><p style="display:none;color:red" id="result">** Empty Value</p></b></i>
</form>

<div id="ajax"></div>
```

and a javascript function

```
<script>
function liveCheck() {
$("#result").show();
}

function search() {
var inp = $("#toSearch").val();
        if(jQuery.trim(inp).length > 0)
 {
jQuery.ajax({
                  url: "load_search_prereg.php",
                  data:{ to : inp },
                  type: "POST",
                  success:function(data){
                  $("#ajax").load('load_search_prereg.php');
                  //alert(data);
                  },
                  error:function (){}
                  });
            }
        else{
          liveCheck();
        }

      }
      </script>
```

And i have my second PHP page named `load_search_prereg.php` to process the POSTed input and the code is

```
<?php
require '../backend/_classes.php';
$x = new DB();
$id = $_POST['to'];
$sql=$x->select(1,'*','tblregistration','app_number',"'$id'");
$fetch = $sql->fetchObject();
var_dump($fetch);
```

The problem is when i clicked the search button in my first PHP page, It displays no array of posted data while im using the `$("#ajax").load('load_search_prereg.php');` method in my javascript. But when i use `alert(data);`, it returns the expected result. Does the problem occur in `$("#ajax").load('load_search_prereg.php');` method ? Help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not:

```
$("#ajax").load('load_search_prereg.php');
```

But:

```
$("#ajax").html(data);
```

I've assumed you just want to write this data into div

edit:
instead of var_dump($fetch); you must return your data a JSON object, eg:

```
$fetch = $sql->fetchObject();
echo json_encode($fetch);
```

Then you can do in js what you want

Comment: yes i ahve done this but in my second PHP page, i want to get the data and  process it.

Comment: But each time you call load_search_prereg.php so right now there is no second page

Comment: And if you really want still call the same script, you must set this data for it, `$("#ajax").load('load_search_prereg.php', {data});`

Comment: curenty using `$("#ajax").load('load_search_prereg.php', {data});` and it returns expected output `array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(52) "
array(1) {
  ["to"]=>
  string(2) "12"
}
"
}` how to get the ["to"] value?

Comment: @BlondePainter makes no sense to make another request for same data that would be returned in `$.ajax`. Will take twice as long with double the chance of a server side problem

Comment: @charlietfl so should i just use the `$("#ajax").html(data);` ?

Comment: I've told you that earlier... What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i have used that @nospor at first but i cannot format it to be inserted as  a table row. im thinking append as a solution to that. sorry i have no background at js

Comment: I've updated my answer. The problem is you must return your data in proper format

Comment: last question sir .is the reason why `$("#ajax").load('load_search_prereg.php');` is not working because it just loads the page(load_search_prereg.php) and not displaying the result of `url: "load_search_prereg.php",` ? enlighten me pls

Comment: your second load didn;t contain data in post

Answer (score -1):

It should be `method:"POST"` instead of `type: "POST"`.

By default method is set to GET.

Comment: it is still in undefined index when i try to get `$_POST['to'];` in load_search_prereg.php